# Ora-01008 with substitution variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have an Oracle query which works fine when I use the command window but does not in an SQL window.

I use Pl/SQL Developer so the command window is like the DOS window.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, &&COLS 
FROM EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY &COLS;
```

So is the error prompted by PL/SQL Developer? Should I use another tool rather than PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: In the field list you've written &&COLS but in the ORDER BY clause you've written &COLS. Is there some fancy syntax I don't know about here whereby the variables should be different in the 2 different contexts?

Comment: I tried to edit your question to make it a bit clearer but I couldn't understand what the word "latter" refers to.

Comment: the double-Ampersand (&&) is used if we want to resuse the variable value without prompting the user each time. So it one time prompts and the use the value each time it finds the &Var.

Comment: and latter reffers to the PL/SQL Developper

Comment: I see. I recommend you delete "related to this latter". The sentence would be much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable substition using the ampersand is a mechanism that's neither part of SQL nor of PL/SQL. It's an extension of SQLplus. The same extension are implemented by Oracle's SQL Developer.

As far as I know, these extension are not implemented by Allround Automations' PL/SQL Developer.